# Return Entire Object from for:each Template in Lightning Web Component (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events, for

Is it possible to return an entire object (not just a single field) from a for:each Template in LWC?

Specifically, I'm not sure why I can't access the object in the same way I can a normal object in object.key notation. See my test below where I hardcoded an object which is output to the console just fine, but is not output to the console when I assign the object pulled from 'event.target.dataset.account'

[image]

getAccountList.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Get Account List">
        <lightning-button label="Get Accounts" onclick={handleGetAccounts}></lightning-button>
        <template for:each={accList.data} for:item="account">
            <lightning-card title={account.Name} icon-name="standard:account" key={account.Id}>
                <lightning-button label="Select Account" onclick={handleSelectAccount} 
                data-account={account} data-account-id={account.Id} data-account-name={account.Name}></lightning-button>
            </lightning-card>
        </template>
</lightning-card>
    html: v.1.7
    js: {version}
</template>
```

getAccountList.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccList from '@salesforce/apex/getAccountListController.getAccList';

export default class GetAccountList extends LightningElement {
    version='v.1.7';
    selAccount;
    @wire(getAccList) accList;
    handleGetAccounts(event){
        console.log('start handleGetAccounts');
        console.log('accList: ',JSON.stringify(this.accList));
        console.log('end handleGetAccounts');
    }
    handleSelectAccount(event){
        console.log('start handleSelectAccount');
        //Test getting simple object
        this.selAccount = {Id: 1, Name: 'David'};
        console.log('JSON.stringify(this.selAccount)', JSON.stringify(this.selAccount));
        console.log('this.selAccount.Id', this.selAccount.Id);
        
        //Cannot get entire object
        this.selAccount = event.target.dataset.account;
        console.log('JSON.stringify(this.selAccount)',JSON.stringify(this.selAccount));
        console.log('this.selAccount.Id',this.selAccount.Id);

        //Get Fields Using Dataset
        console.log('event.currentTarget.dataset.accountId',event.currentTarget.dataset.accountId);
        console.log('event.currentTarget.dataset.accountName',event.currentTarget.dataset.accountName);
        
        //Get Fields Using getAttribute
        console.log('event.target.getAttribute(\'data-account-id\')',event.target.getAttribute('data-account-id'));
        console.log('event.target.getAttribute(\'data-account-name\')',event.target.getAttribute('data-account-name'));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Properties set in `data-` properties automatically have `toString()` called on them during template rendering, as all `data-` properties must be string values. This results in the value `[object Object]` being placed inside the property. You can't deserialize this data later, because the damage has already been done by the time your code has control. You'll have to get the account from the list of accounts, given its account Id, or `JSON.stringify` the data you want to store in a data attribute, which you can then reverse in your code.

```
this.selAccount = this.accList.data.find(
  (account) => account.Id === event.target.dataset.accountId
);
```